# c++ Checking if a string is an isogram

Tags: c++

So I'm starting out and doing some code challenges in between book and tutorial learning and was hoping to get some general feedback on code readability and use of comments.

I know it's sometimes hard to understand your own code after you wrote it so my question is - how easy is it to understand this one based on comments?

Do you think I'm missing anything crucial? Any general feedback welcome, thanks.

```
/*
https://edabit.com/challenge/SEzYX5qtTR4WcZeR3
An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or 
nonconsecutive.Create a function that takes a string and returns
either true or false depending on whether or not it's an "isogram".
Examples
isIsogram("Algorism") ➞ true
isIsogram("PasSword") ➞ false
// Not case sensitive.
isIsogram("Consecutive") ➞ false
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h> // to use the toupper function which takes a letter
character and returns the upper case ASCII integer
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input_string;
    string output_string;
    bool isogram_check = true; // by default the program assumes that    everything is an isogram and then tries to find repeating letters to assert that it's not an isogram

    cout << "Enter a string." << endl;
    cin >> input_string;

    for (int i = 0; i < input_string.length(); i++) // this loop takes the input string and converts it to all upper case letters.
    {
        output_string = output_string + char(toupper(input_string[i])); 
    }

    // cout << output_string << endl;
    // the above line is to test the toupper output

    for (int i = 0; i < output_string.length(); i++)       // the first loop decides WHAT to compare to something else, the second loops decides what that SOMETHING ELSE is.
    {
        for (int o = i+1; o < output_string.length(); o++) // this loop takes the character at position i and compares it to the character at i+1 then i+2, etc. by iterating o.
        {                                                  // in the above comment, i+1 = o since we iterated i once right at the beginning.
            if (output_string[i] == output_string[o])      // when the loop finds two of the same character within the string it brakes out of both loops
            {
                isogram_check = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isogram_check == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isogram_check == false)
    {
        cout << input_string << " is not an isogram.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << input_string << " is an isogram.\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?r=SearchResults&s=1|1145.5940) `using namespace std`.

Keep your lines shorter.  Having to constantly scroll back and forth to read lines is unpleasant.  Most of your comments should be on one (or more) lines right before the statement being commented on.  Also, avoid obvious things in comments (like "resets i to use in the next loop.").

Declare variables as close as possible to their first use.

Since `isogram_check` is a `bool`, you can test it with `!isogram_check` instead of `isogram_check == false`.

With a slight change in algorithm (searching characters before the ith one), your two `while` loops can be combined into one. Although there are other ways to do this that could be better (for some definition of "better"), your implementation is a quick first pass that works well for short strings (but less well as the strings get longer).

Comment: Thanks. I am intentionally using the namespace declaration since I know I won't be using other namespaces. Should I avoid it even knowing the issue that can come up?


What would I use to combine the 2 loops? My idea is that since I need to iterate both the WHAT I'm comparing and the what I'm comparing TO that I need 2 loops.

Comment: @ChirilRussu you never know which namespace you need in the future, so it's best to avoid that. One of my employers' projects uses `namespace std` everywhere and causes a lot of name clashes problems that we have to do some workaround to avoid to much code change

Comment: @ChirilRussu - Quoting from the zen of python, "Namespaces are one honking great idea — let's do more of those!" The same concept very much applies to C++. The key intent of namespaces is to avoid collisions. It's best to avoid "using namespace <namespace_name>", ever.

Answer (score 6):

I am not an expert in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) but your code seems verbose. You can try to make it more explicit for a person who knows better [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) better. Plus the algorithm is not that hard to digest so writing some built-in constructions will not overcome the ability to understand the whole flow.

Unless your task is not bound by memory you can use `std::set` to do the counting of unique characters for you and squeeze out some lines of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    std::string input_string;
    std::cout << "Enter a string." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input_string;

    std::unordered_set<char> chars;

    std::cout << input_string << (std::all_of(
        input_string.begin(), 
        input_string.end(),
        [&chars](const char c) {
            auto upper = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
            //                                 ^  ^  ^
            //                         avoid undefined behaviour
            return chars.insert(upper).second;
        }
    ) ?
        " is an isogram.\n" :
        " is not an isogram.\n");

}
```

I see you're probably trying to practice for coding interviews or just exercising your problem-solving skills, either way, you should think about using the stl of the given language.

What I mean is not using sorting functions when you are asked to do sorting challenge, but rather use some built-in algorithms as an intermediary step before achieving what your goal is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning that's why I don't know the best ways to do things. For example I don't know how `transform` works, never used `.begin` or `.end.` Don't know how `set` works, etc. Now that you wrote them for me I can just look it up and figure it out, but it's sort of I don't know what I don't know type of situation while I'm still learning.

Comment: @ChirilRussu, well `set` is a data structure that only keeps unique elements, so it maintains uniqueness for you. So now you probably see that if `set.size()` is equal to `input_string.size()` this means that all chars from `input_string` got into the `set` => they are all unique

Comment: @ChirilRussu `.begin` and `.end` are methods that return `iterator` to a certain point of the caller - in this case the `set`. You can think of them as start and end indexes until you feel comfortable to dig down into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern

Comment: @ChirilRussu, `transform` is just a function that takes start and end iterator (you can think of index) and applies some function to each element that this iterator is traversing in this case its the `string`

Answer (score 3):

You have two `while` loops that have a counter `i` that is incremented. You should really use a `for` loop.

Your algorithm has quadratic complexity. Can you come up with something that is linear? To be fair, I can immediately only think of a linear solution that has a way higher proportionality constant, so it will be faster only for very long strings. Still.... worth exploring.

Comment: Thanks, I changed both while loops to for loops and got rid of the global i.

Comment: so `!isogram_check` works, just to clarify my understanding that is the same as `isogram_check != initialized value` ?

Comment: right, `something==false` is the same as `!something`

Answer (score 3):

Many good comments have been made already, eg:

- code in a function
- limit source code witdth to to 80-100 columns
- code is overly complex for the task, hard to digest it

Try to use the [available algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and [data structures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Those are reference links, but many good articles and [books have been written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

One good way to solve many problems related to "frequency of occurrence" is to produce a "count of unique occurrence" or "frequency".  Arguably the canonical tool for this is `std:unordered_map`, which uses a `hashtable` internally. Often it is combined with `std::partial_sort_copy` to find the "10 most frequent" or similar. We don't need `sort_copy` here because we can return false on first repeat. There is an suggested code for the `is_isogram()` function using `std::unordered_map` with some static calls from `main()` below.

But the problem here is even simpler, because we don't actually need to know how many repeats there are I have provide a second function `is_isogram_set()` which uses an `std::unordered_set`. I ran some quick benchmarks and the `std::unordered_set` is about 5-10% faster than the `std::unordered_map`.

If we can assume "ASCII only" text, and ignore nonalpha completely, then all uppercase'd characters will be between 'A' - 'Z' and we could sensibly use something like a `std::array<bool>` for which I have provided a third sample `is_isogram_array()`. This is signignificantly (~10-15x !) faster than the other 2 options.

Any of these should be easily understood by anyone with C++ experience, rather than unpicking "[several custom raw loops](https://youtu.be/qH6sSOr-yk8)". Using the standard containers allows us to focus on clean efficient code, rather than "loop correctness". So we were easily able to find significant speed/feature trade-offs.

**EDIT**: Based on a suggestion from @LaurentLARIZZA I added an alternative version of the `std::array` variant which uses the STL algorithm `std::all_of`. I named it `is_isogram_array_algo()`. I doesn't fundamentally change anything, but it does allow us to avoid the ranged for loop and to make the code slightly more self documenting. ie we can name the lambda "unseen" and write "all of unseen", which arguably makes it slightly clearer what is going on. Code is slightly longer, but has identical performance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>

bool is_isogram(const std::string& str) {
  auto freqs = std::unordered_map<char, int>{};
  for (auto&& c: str) {
    if (auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); std::isalpha(uc)) {
      int& count = freqs[std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(uc))];
      if (count > 0) return false;
      count++;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool is_isogram_set(const std::string& str) {
  auto freqs = std::unordered_set<char>{};
  for (auto&& c: str) {
    if (auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); std::isalpha(uc)) {
      auto [iter, was_new] = freqs.insert(std::toupper(uc));
      if (!was_new) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool is_isogram_array(const std::string& str) {
  auto freqs = std::array<bool, 26>{false};
  for (auto&& c: str) {
    if (auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); std::isalpha(uc)) {
      int idx = std::toupper(uc) - 'A';
      if (freqs[idx]) return false;
      freqs[idx] = true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool is_isogram_array_algo(const std::string& str) {
  auto freqs = std::array<bool, 26>{false};

  auto unseen = [&freqs](char c) {
    if (auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); std::isalpha(uc)) {
      int idx = std::toupper(uc) - 'A';
      if (freqs[idx]) return false;
      freqs[idx] = true;
    }
    return true;
  };

  return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), unseen);
}



int main() {

  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "Algorism=" << is_isogram("Algorism") << '\n'
            << "PasSword=" << is_isogram("PasSword") << '\n'
            << "Consecutive=" << is_isogram("Consecutive") << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `auto c : str` here. For why I wouldn't use `auto&&` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-forwarding-references-in-range-based-for-loops/13130795#13130795), and copying chars is cheap.

Comment: I don't disagree. In fact i had it that way and changed last minute before posting. Trying to make `for (auto&& e: ..)` a habit because "it always works": https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/15/autorefref-always-works/

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting point as well!

Comment: Just did a test for a simplified (to get rid of map and iostream boilerplate code) example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/2R3YdU  I copy pasted the ASM for auto and for auto&& and the diff is precisely `nil`. I am not saying it will always be, in fact this example is "too simple" as it gets SIMD vector optimised etc etc. But in general could we assume that auto&& will not gen "worse" code? I agree it looks "fishy" if you're not used to it though...

Comment: Would an [`unordered_multiset`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_multiset/) also be a fitting data structure to represent the concept of a "histogram"? I don't know C++, but that's what I would use in a different language (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/233584/1581), even going so far as to implement my own (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644639/2988).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I would not reach for a multiset here, no. The use case is about frequency (at least in my mind), any freq > 1 must return false. A multiset will store all the characters, inclduding the repeats. So we feed it the complete works of shakespeare http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100 . Then you will get a very large (!) multiset. Where an unordered_map (with toupper and assuming ASCII only) will give you at most 26 entries. We want to store unique(!) chars -> int counts. and unordered_map does exactly that.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, C++'s multiset actually behaves less like a multiset but more like a *bag* ("unordered vector"). I missed that. Today I learned something new!

Comment: Well, your algorithm is the same in all 3 cases, it is basically `std::all_of` with a stateful predicate that determines "whether the current character has never been encountered before". (noting this just because you suggest to use *the available algorithms*) You're making your predicate implementation vary.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Yep you could do that. We could debate what "std::all_of" adds here? The key part of the algorithm would go into the predicate lambda, ie tracking which letters have been seen. Why don't you provide an answer that does that, and we can compare?

Comment: @OliverSchonrock: Sure. Here you go https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235167/35322

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA I added such a version above. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @OliverSchonrock : No. Have a look at my answer, Your `freqs` variables belong to the predicate. I made them full-fledged funciton objects instead of lambdas.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA
Yeah I saw. Yours is good too. This entire question has all got hefty smell of over engineering to it now. The task is trivial. The OP made a meal of it. The highest rated answer is not great. But hey. I am kinda done with it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Oliver Schonrock's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235116/35322), here is an equivalent version of the code leveraging the `std::all_of` algorithm. Note that I did not try to change the semantics of given in Oliver's answer, as all three structures could be made much shorter by always counting, and using bitwise operations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>


struct IsFirstOccurrence_UM {
  bool operator()(char c) {
    int& count = freqs[std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(uc))];
    if (count > 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      count++;
      return true;
    }
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<char, int> freqs;
};

struct IsFirstOccurrence_Set {
  bool operator()(char c) {
    if (auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); std::isalpha(uc)) {
      auto [iter, was_new] = freqs.insert(std::toupper(uc));
      return was_new;
    } else {
      return true; // Note that non-alpha characters are always considered first-occurrence
    }
  }
private:
  std::unordered_set<char> freqs;
};

struct IsFirstOccurrence_Array {
  bool operator()(char c) {
    if (auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c); std::isalpha(uc)) {
      int idx = std::toupper(uc) - 'A';
      if (freqs[idx])  {
        return false;
      } else {
        freqs[idx] = true;
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true; // Note that non-alpha characters are always considered first-occurrence
    }
  }
private:
  std::array<bool, 26> freqs{false};
};

template<typename IsFirstOccurrencePedicate>
bool is_isogram(const std::string& str, IsFirstOccurrencePedicate is_first_occurrence) {
  return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::move(is_first_occurrence));
}

int main() {

  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "Algorism=" << is_isogram("Algorism", IsFirstOccurrence_UM()) << '\n'
            << "PasSword=" << is_isogram("PasSword", IsFirstOccurrence_UM()) << '\n'
            << "Consecutive=" << is_isogram("Consecutive", IsFirstOccurrence_UM()) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, nice. Demonstrates something slightly different. I also added a version above using `std::all_of` using a lambda, so without the templated reuse. I viewed the 3 options as mutually exclusive alternatives, and you would keep only one. I think we are beginning to overthink this trivial problem ;-)

Comment: Yes we are. That's why I avoided fleshing out the `IsFirstOccurrencePredicate` concept :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the "efficiency" focused options in my other answer, here is an option which is just very terse. Given we can't have words > 26 characters which are isograms, this might be just enough?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <cctype>

bool is_isogram(std::string s) {
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); });
  return std::unordered_set<char>(s.begin(), s.end()).size() == s.size();
}
```

It's closer (!) to what one might write in a language like python.

```py
def is_isogram(s):
  return len(s) == len(set(s.upper()))
```